# Principal submatrix of of a rank deficient matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am self-studying Matrix Analysis Book Roger Horn. I appreciate any comment or response to the following problem from the book (Problem 1.3.p16):

Let $A \in M_n$ and suppose that $n > \text{rank} A = r \ge 1$. If $A$ is similar to $B ⊕ 0_{n−r}$ (so $B \in M_r$ is nonsingular), show that A has a nonsingular $r$-by-$r$ principal submatrix.

Comment: Sorry. My answer was wrong because I was wrong about what a principal submatrix is.

Comment: Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Here is a proof for $r=1$: Note that the similarity condition (independent of what $r$ is) is equivalent to $\operatorname{im}A\cap\ker A = \{0\}$. Now, assume that the diagonal of $A$ is zero. Denote by $a_k$ the $k$-th column of $A$. There is some $j$ such that $a_j\neq 0$. If $a_{ij}\neq 0$ for some $i\neq j$, then $a_i=0$ because otherwise $a_i$ and $a_j$ would be linearly independent. Hence,$$Aa_j = A\sum_{i=1}^na_{ij}e_i = \sum_{i=1}^na_{ij}a_i = 0$$and so $a_j\in \operatorname{im}A\cap\ker A = \{0\}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Horn-Johnson, Theorem 1.4.9 is your friend. ;-) Note that the similarity condition means that the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda = 0$ is exactly $n-r$. Setting $k=n-r+1$ in the theorem leads you to the desired conclusion.

Comment: @amsmath Thanks! I think it is Theorem 1.4.10 (I have the second edition). In Theorem 1.4.10, (b) implies (c), but it seems that we need the converse for this question. Also, I think we cannot use (a) because we do not know the geometric multiplicity.

Comment: Arthur, we need that (b) implies (c). So, put $k := n-r+1$ and let us assume that every principle $r\times r$ submatrix is singular (and thus has $\lambda = 0$ as an eigenvalue). Then (b) is satisfied for any $m > n-k = r-1$ since $A$ has rank $r$. By the theorem, (c) applies which says that $\lambda =0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with alg. multiplicity at least $n-r+1$, which contradicts the similarity assumption.

Comment: I made this an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Theorem 1.4.10 from the book to prove that. The theorem says, in particular, the following:

> If all principal submatrices of $A$ of size larger than $s$ have zero
>   as an eigenvalue, then zero is an eigenvalue of $A$ with algebraic
>   multiplicity at least $n-s$.

If we assume that all the principal submatrices of size $r$ of the rank $r$-matrix $A$ are singular, they all have zero as an eigenvalue. The same holds for the (principal) submatrices of larger size because $A$ has rank $r$. So, the condition in the above statement holds with $s = r-1$. Therefore, zero is an eigenvalue of $A$ with algebraic multiplicity at least $n-r+1$. But the alg. mult. of zero for $A$ is the same as the alg. mult. of zero for $B\oplus 0$, which is, obviously, $n-r$. A contradiction!

Comment: Thanks a lot for making this an answer and adding details.